# Get innerHTML from table

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a popup that displays the Price of FTC when the table loads using javascript. I'm running my script using GreaseMonkey in Firefox.

The site I'm running my code on is: https://www.coinmkt.com/#/
The code below does run the script once, but my innerHTML is undefined. Can anyone help me return the value of FTC? Thanks in advance:

```
function myScript(){
    if(document.getElementById('reverse-exchange-rates')){
        alert(document.getElementById('reverse-exchange-rates').getElementsByTagName('td')[5].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].InnerHTML);
        clearInterval(RunNewIteration);
    }
    var RunNewInteration = setTimeout(myScript, 5000);
}

myScript();
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML that you are trying to parse?

Comment: You have several problems in your code [look at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/RRPcP/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **should be**:

```
innerHTML
```

**Not**:

```
InnerHTML
```

The first letter must be small-case.

Comment: Wow I feel sheepish ... baa. Thanks matewka.

Answer (score 0):

copy/paste this! `innerHtml` was wrongly spelled

```
function myScript(){
if(document.getElementById('reverse-exchange-rates')){
    alert(document.getElementById('reverse-exchange-rates').getElementsByTagName('td')[5].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
    clearInterval(RunNewIteration);
}
var RunNewInteration = setTimeout(myScript, 5000);
}

 myScript();
```